# Git pull into an untracked copy of repo

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-pull

So in an ideal world, when I started this project, I would have cloned from a source, and then committed all my changes to this repo. When the main project was updated, I could pull those changes into my repo. (This is one way traffic, no pushing going on.)

However, when I started, I did not clone, but simply downloaded a released ZIP of the code, unzipped it, and then did a `git init`. I have since committed all my changes to this copy of the code. However, the main codebase has now been updated, but as my copy is not a merge, but my own repo of the same base code, I cannot merge the master's changes into mine.

Is there any way of getting these changes from the main code into my repo without having to start again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix your repository by rebasing the changes of your private repository on top of the remote changes.

- add a new remote to your repository containing the correct remote git URL.
- fetch from that remote to fetch all the correct remote commits to your own repository
- use `git rebase` to transplant you commits  on top of the remote commits.
- merge your branch into the remote one.

This would be something like:

```
cd $your_git_repository
git remote add origin $URL
git fetch origin
git branch -m my_branch
git rebase --onto $base_commit $your_first_commit my_branch
git merge $remote_branch
git log --graph --decorate --oneline
```

where `$base_commit` is the commit corresponding to the zip you downloaded in the first place, and `$your_first_commit` is the commit you commited the extracted zip file as.

Comment: Thanks :) Will this work if other people work on my repo? (When I say 'my repo', it's actually on a shared server that many of us commit to.)

Comment: Rebasing creates new commits. Assuming you are talking about a central repository with a few people working on a private clone of it, you need all those people to push their local changes and delete their local repository. After the rebase they need a fresh clone of the central repository. This should result in exactly the same content, but a different history. Be aware that commits of the old repository are no longer valid, and strange things will happen if someone happens to push old commits to the new repository.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way - clone the latest version of code into, say `folderA`. Say you were working in the unzipped source in `folderB`. Copy `folderB` contents into `folderA`. Commit the changes. Push!

Comment: This way you will save the content but loose all of your own commits.

Comment: @michas - true, but this is the simplest way and a valid way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do, assuming you are on branch master:

```
git remote add origin
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories origin master
```

And then merge the two repos.

If you have more branches, use `git merge` with the same `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag

- Flag added in [git 2.9](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt#L58-L68)
- More info in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---allow-unrelated-histories)